# Data Alignment, Data Structure Padding and C

Tags: c

Alguém pode me explicar como o processar/compilar faz o padding?
Eu não entendo porque a estrutura structc_t tem um tamanho de 24, não deveria ser 16 igual a estrutura structd_t?
Nota: Dados em processador Intel 64 bits, Windows de 64 bits

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Dados em processador Intel 64 bits, Windows de 64 bits
typedef struct structa_tag{
   char        c; // size 1
   short int   s; // size 2
} structa_t; // size 3 + 1 Padding = 4 bytes
typedef struct structb_tag{
   short int   s; // size 2
   char        c; // size 1
   int         i; // size 4
} structb_t; // size 7 + 1 Padding = 8 bytes
typedef struct structc_tag{
   char        c; // size 1
   double      d; // size 8
   int         s; // size 4
} structc_t; // size 13 + 11 Padding = 24 bytes
typedef struct structd_tag{
   double      d; // size 8
   int         s; // size 4
   char        c; // size 1
} structd_t; // size 13 + 3 Padding = 16 bytes
void main(){
   structa_t A; structb_t B; structc_t C; structd_t D;
   printf("sizeof(structa_t) = %d\n", sizeof(A));
   printf("sizeof(structb_t) = %d\n", sizeof(B));
   printf("sizeof(structc_t) = %d\n", sizeof(C));
   printf("sizeof(structd_t) = %d\n", sizeof(D));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Variáveis em C não são colocadas em um endereço de memória arbitrário. Cada tipo primitivo (com exceção de `char`, que ocupa 1 byte) tem um requisito de alinhamento, que é o tipo de endereço (em byte) onde ela pode estar localizada. `char`s podem se localizar em qualquer endereço, `short` (2 bytes) precisam estar em endereços divisíveis por 2; `int` (e `float`) em endereços divisíveis por 4, e `double` (e `long long`) endereços divisíveis por 8. Estas regras de alinhamento tornam o acesso às variáveis mais eficiente, pois esse "alinhamento natural" facilita que instruções de assembly simples consigam acessar o dado.

No caso da `structc_t`, o padding é adicionado entre os membros `c` e `d` para garantir que o membro do tipo `double` esteja armazenado em uma posição de memória múltipla de 8. Na `structd_t` como o `double` é o primeiro elemento, esse padding de 7 bytes não é necessário.

```
typedef struct structc_tag{
   char        c; // size 1
   char        pad0[7];
   double      d; // size 8
   int         s; // size 4
   char        pad1[4];
} structc_t;

typedef struct structd_tag{
   double      d; // size 8
   int         s; // size 4
   char        c; // size 1
   char        pad0[3];
} structd_t; // size 13 + 3 Padding = 16 bytes
```

Da mesma forma, se você tivesse invertido a ordem dos membros do tipo `int` e `char` da segunda estrutura, veria que o tamanho dela também seria diferente:

```
typedef struct structb2_tag {
   short int   s; // size 2
   int         i; // size 4
   char        c; // size 1
} structb2_t; // size 7 + 5 Padding = 12 bytes
```

é equivalente a

```
typedef struct structb2_tag {
   short int   s; // size 2
   char        pad0[2];
   int         i; // size 4
   char        c; // size 1
   char        pad1[3];
} structb2_t; // size 7 + 5 Padding = 12 bytes
```

Pra completar, o padding do final da estrutura é adicionado para garantir que o seu tamanho seja múltiplo do maior de seus membros. No caso da `structb2_t` acima, precisa de mais 3 bytes para ser múltiplo de 4 (tamanho do campo inteiro), e no caso da `structc_t` seria mais 4 bytes para ser múltiplo de 8 (tamanho do campo `double`). Isso é necessário para o caso da estrutura ser usada em um array, por exemplo, onde os elementos são armazenados de forma contígua na memória, e as regras de alinhamento sejam preservadas.

Esse [documento (inglês)](https://wr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/_media/teaching/wintersemester_2013_2014/epc-14-haase-svenhendrik-alignmentinc-paper.pdf) tem uma boa descrição sobre padding em C de modo geral.