# Tamanho de um caracter (ASCII vs outras codificações) em bytes

Tags: c, c++, char, byte, teoria-da-computação

Vendo [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178443/um-tipo-char-sempe-tem-tamanho-1-mesmo/178444?noredirect=1#comment368700_178444) surgiu-me uma duvida, vindo de PHP e no passado tendo "problemas" derivados da codificação de caracteres, ex: [`srtpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) vs [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php), eu sabia que todos os caracteres ASCII têm 1 byte, mas pensava que caracteres especiais teriam mais, eu associava que ao facto que um caractere ser especial este também seria *multi byte*.

Ou seja se eu gravar um `simples.txt` com um caractere "a", por ex, este fica com tamanho de 1 byte, mas se gravar com um caractere "ã" este fica com dois bytes. Mas [esse exemplo](http://ideone.com/3XvJLc) indica que o caractere especial tem 4 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    cout << sizeof(char) << "\n"; // 1
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\n"; // 1
    cout << sizeof('ã')  << "\n"; // 4
}
```

Em que é que ficamos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O tipo `char` em C, e consequentemente em C++, não tem lá um bom nome. Na verdade acho que ele deveria chamar `byte`, porque é isso que ele é. Ele ser usado como um caractere é só um detalhe.

Ao contrário da crença popular, C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca. Ela é estaticamente tipada, mas fraca. [As pessoas não entendem muito bem esse termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/101). C pode interpretar o mesmo dado como se fosse de um tipo ou forma diferente da originalmente intendida. Isso pode ser observado nesse código:

```
char a = 'a';
printf("%c\n", a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9rPc9Y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qppfobib-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/MultiByteChar.c).

O mesmo dado pode ser apresentado como número ou caractere.

Algumas funções do C permitem fazer essa interpretação como um caractere, em geral você precisa dizer que deve ser assim. Por isso existe o `%c`. Ele indica que o dado deve ser tratado como um caractere. No geral um `char` é tratado como número mesmo.

Qualquer codificação de caracteres que podem ser armazenadas em 1 byte pode ser armazenada em um `char`. Quando C foi criada só existia o ASCII mesmo (pelo menos de forma relevante).

Foram surgindo outras codificações mais completas que usam o byte todo para representar mais caracteres. Foi ficando complicado, criaram páginas de *charset*. Para "simplificar" e habilitar mais caracteres criaram o caractere multi-byte. Nesse momento não foi mais possível usar `char` como o tipo para armazenar o caractere, já que foi garantido que ele só deveria ter 1 byte.

Na impede você usar uma sequência de `char`s para dizer que é apenas um caractere, mas será uma solução sua, que suas funções sabem o que fazer. A biblioteca do C, de terceiros, inclusive dos sistemas operacionais não sabem como lidar com isso. Então ninguém faz. Muita gente não entende que C é uma linguagem para trabalhar com as coisas de forma bruta, você pode fazer o que quiser do jeito que quiser. Sair do padrão é um problema seu.

Quando precisamos do caractere multi-byte costumamos usar o tipo [`wchar_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide). Ele pode ter um tamanho variável de acordo com a implementação. A especificação deixa livre. Em alguns casos usamos o `char16_ t` e o `char32_ t` que tem seus tamanhos garantidos por especificação. Isto é padronizado.

Vamos executar esse código para entender melhor:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'ã';
wchar_t c = 'a';
wchar_t d = 'ã';
cout << sizeof(char) << "\n";
cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
cout << sizeof('a') << "\n";
cout << sizeof(b)  << "\n";
cout << sizeof(c)  << "\n";
cout << sizeof(d)  << "\n";
cout << sizeof('ã')  << "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/4ljwlI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CharAccentcpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/MultiByteChar.cpp).

Percebeu que o acento não faz ocupar mais bytes? Declarei `b` como `char` ele ele tem apenas um byte, mesmo tendo acento? E que `c` tem 4 bytes mesmo tem um caractere que cabe no ASCII? O tamanho é determinado pelo tipo do dado, ou da variável. Onde eu disse explicitamente que é `char` ele usou 1 byte. Onde ele pode inferir que um `char` é suficiente ele usou 1 byte, onde eu disse explicitamente que é um `wchar_ t`, ocupou 4 bytes. Onde ele inferiu que precisava de mais de um byte para representar o caractere ele adotou 4 bytes. Então o seu `sizeof('ã')` deu 4 bytes porque houve inferência que ele seria do tipo `wchar_ t`.

Ficou claro que nesse compilador o `wchar_t` tem 4 bytes.

Toda biblioteca do C e do C++ entende o `wchar_ t` como um tipo para armazenar caracteres e não números, ainda que sempre o que tem lá sejam números, computadores não sabem o que são caracteres, ele só usa um truque para mostrar isso pra gente que quer ver isso.

Novamente em C você faz como deseja. Se quer fazer que todos caracteres tenham um byte dá para fazer, mesmo que eles possuam acento. Claro que existem apenas 256 valores possível em um byte. Não dá para ter todos caracteres possíveis nessa situação.

Comment: Obrigado, o facto de ter declarado b como char faz com que não o imprima corretamente: http://ideone.com/JshA87 . Já no meu computador `b` é impresso como aquilo que tão bem conhecemos, um quadradinho com um "?" dentro

Comment: @Miguel sim, o `cout` não sabe como lidar com isso. É o que eu falei, você tem que criar suas próprias funções para lidar com isso. Por isso nem demonstrei esse uso, demonstrei que pode usar 1 byte. Tudo isso está na resposta. Como lidar é detalhe de implementação. É possível configurar isso, mas já é outro problema :)

Comment: Exato bigown, obrigado, de facto pensei que o tamanho de um caracter fosse universal (não sei porquê), talvez porque sigo muito http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ e eles aqui vêm sempre um byte como um caracter (ASCII)

Comment: Só um "à parte" `printf("%d\n", a);` , isto se não me engano imprime o código ASCII referente ao caracter 'a' (97): http://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/1/24/59/98/20140923/ob_806ac6_codigo-ascii.jpg

Comment: O normal é tratar como 1 byte mesmo. O caractere não tem tamanho o universal, nem o tipo tem, depende do compilador, arquitetura, plataforma. Na verdade sua segunda observação é o oposto :P `printf("%c\n", a);` imprime o caractere definido na tabela ASCIII para 97, porque o normal para C é o número mesmo, é que todo mundo acostumou mais com o caractere. `char` é um tipo numérico, não é um texto. Ele pode ser usado como se fosse texto.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR; Depende do encoding e de alguns detalhes da linguagem/plataforma.**

Cada caracter UTF-8 ocupa 1 a 6 bytes,

Cada caracter UTF-16 ocupa 16 bits

Cada caracter UTF-32 ocupa 32 bits

Cada caracter duma string ascii ocupa 1 byte

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290252/1698682)

---

Bom, creio que é bom lembrar apenas que quando voce trabalha com uma linguagem/plataforma ela é livre de decidir como vai alocar espaco em memória para cada um dos tipos sopurtados.

**C**

No caso do `C` ele faz o trabalho mínimo, ele aloca espaco suficiente para o tipo e pode acrescentar alguns bytes extra para padding, para ser mais amigável de os armazenar em cache e ler/escrever em memória.

[Veja esta pergunta para mais informacoes no C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29612/data-alignment-data-structure-padding-and-c)

**C#**

No caso do `C#` por exemplo todos os objetos nao primitivos tem um overhead de 8 ou 16 bytes, [esta pergunta também esclarece o porque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161846/como-uma-classe-%C3%A9-organizada-na-mem%C3%B3ria).

**Python**

**Objetos**

O python também usa uma técninca semelhante á do `C#`. A resposta a esta pergunta no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value) indica que **todos** os objetos em Python ocupam 16bytes extra (em 64bits). Parece que todos os objetos armazenam uma contagem de referencias e uma referencia para o tipo do objeto. Existe a documentacao oficial do python que explica [como um objéto é estruturado](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html).

[Encontrei um artigo bastante detalhado neste assunto](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609)

Parece que o Python também faz padding de objetos até 256bytes, se voce alocar um objeto de 10bytes ele na realidade vai ocupar 16.

**Strings**

Ele também dá mais detalhes sobre o tamanho que uma string ocupa.

Uma string vazia ocupa 37bytes, cada caracter adicional adiciona um byte ao tamanho. As strings Unicode sao semelhantesmas elas tem um overhead de 50 bytes e cada caracter adicional ocupa 4 bytes (creio que houve um erro dado pelo autor). No python 3 o overhead é de 49 bytes.

A informacao parece ser um bocado contraditória da que é dada numa pergunta no SOEN. Mas isso vai depender da versao do python que estiver a usar, por isso fica aqui para referencia.

[Esta outra pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python) também tem uma tabela que explica quanto espaco cada objeto ocupa.

> ```
> Bytes  type        empty + scaling notes
> 24     int         NA
> 28     long        NA
> 37     str         + 1 byte per additional character
> 52     unicode     + 4 bytes per additional character
> 56     tuple       + 8 bytes per additional item
> 72     list        + 32 for first, 8 for each additional
> 232    set         sixth item increases to 744; 22nd, 2280; 86th, 8424
> 280    dict        sixth item increases to 1048; 22nd, 3352; 86th, 12568 *
> 64     class inst  has a __dict__ attr, same scaling as dict above
> 16     __slots__   class with slots has no dict, seems to store in 
>                    mutable tuple-like structure.
> 120    func def    doesn't include default args and other attrs
> 904    class def   has a proxy __dict__ structure for class attrs
> 104    old class   makes sense, less stuff, has real dict though.
> ```

Comment: pequena correção: utf16: The encoding is variable-length, as code points are encoded with one or two 16-bit code units.

Comment: Outra correção: desde a criação do UTF-16, o UTF-8 não pode mais ter nem 5 nem 6 bytes, já que basta 4 para codificar 0x10FFFF.