# Como o computador "sabe" a ordem alfabética ao comparar dois chars?

Tags: c, c++, char

Tenho este programa de cifra de César:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout<<"Enter the message:\n";
   char msg[100];
   cin.getline(msg,100); //take the message as input
   int i, j, length,choice,key;
   cout << "Enter key: ";
   cin >> key; //take the key as input
   length = strlen(msg);
   cout<<"Enter your choice \n1. Encryption \n2. Decryption \n";
   cin>>choice;
   if (choice==1) //for encryption{
      char ch;
      for(int i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
         ch = msg[i];
         //encrypt for lowercase letter
         if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'z') {
               ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }  
            msg[i] = ch;
         }
         //encrypt for uppercase letter
         else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'Z'){
               ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            msg[i] = ch;
         }
      }
      printf("Encrypted message: %s", msg);
   }
```

Estou com dúvida na passagem:

```
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
    ch = ch + key;
    if (ch > 'z') {
        ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1
```

Não entendi a comparação com a letra `'a'`. Como o programa sabe que o alfabeto é de "a" a "z", sem uma definição? Isso é padrão do C/C++? Também não entendi as comparações do tipo char (`ch >= 'a'`).

Comment: isso se chama "tabela ASCII", onde cada caractere, nesse caso as letras de "a" a "z" tem um código: https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: De cara, noto que o `**If` e o `If` deveriam ser escritos como `if`.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Põe isso como resposta, por mais simples que seja.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema (lembrando que só pode aceitar uma delas) - caso elas não tenham resolvido, fique à vontade para comentar explicando o que faltou, que se for o caso, podemos atualizar as respostas

Answer (score 9):

> *Como o programa sabe que o alfabeto é de "a" a "z", sem uma definição?*

É claro que existe uma definição. Como um professor da faculdade costumava dizer, computadores são máquinas "burras", porque só fazem o que a gente manda. Se ele "sabe" a ordem alfabética, é porque alguém colocou essa regra lá.

---

O `char`, apesar do nome, é um tipo numérico. Na verdade [ele deveria se chamar `byte`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178483/112052), pois no fundo ele é isso.

O que acontece é que esse número *pode* ser interpretado como um caractere, usando o seu respectivo valor na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```c
char c = 'a';
printf("%d\n", c); // 97
printf("%c\n", c); // a
```

Na tabela ASCII, as letras possuem valores consecutivos que coincidem com a ordem alfabética. Então a letra `a` tem o valor 97, a letra `b` é 98, etc. Detalhe que as letras maiúsculas possuem valores diferentes: `A` é 65, `B` é 66, etc.

Enfim, como esses valores no fundo são números, posso fazer operações com eles normalmente, como incrementar seu valor e comparar com outros:

```c
char c = 'a';
printf("%d\n", c); // 97
printf("%c\n", c); // a

c += 3; // somar 3 ao valor do char
printf("%d\n", c); // 100
printf("%c\n", c); // d
// o código entra em ambos os if's abaixo
if (c > 97) {
    printf("maior que 97\n");
}
if (c < 'f') { // o caractere "f" tem o valor 102
    printf("antes de f\n");
}
```

Lembrando que isso não se restringe a somente letras:

```c
char c = '!';
printf("%d\n", c); // 33
printf("%c\n", c); // !
if (c < '}') { // entra no if, pois o valor do caractere "}" é 125
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

---

Portanto, neste trecho:

```c
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    ch = ch + key;
    if (ch > 'z') {
        ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
```

Estou comparando se o `char` está entre `'a'` e `'z'` (que seria o mesmo que verificar se ele está entre 97 e 122, mas usar os caracteres deixa o código mais fácil de entender, na minha opinião).

O segundo `if` verifica se o resultado ultrapassou o `z` (por exemplo, se o resultado for 123, que corresponde ao caractere `{`), então ele corrige, fazendo com que corresponda a uma letra (já que a ideia da [Cifra de César](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) é voltar para o `a` caso a letra ultrapasse o `z`).

Mas na verdade tem um problema aí, [pois o `char`, dependendo do compilador, pode ser *signed* por *default*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941), o que significa que seus valores serão de -128 a 127, então se o valor ultrapassar 127 ocorrerá um *overflow* e este se tornará negativo ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/kpLvAm)).

Uma forma de resolver é garantir que o valor não ultrapasse 127:

```c
char msg[5] = "azAZ";
int key = 10;
for (int i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    char ch = msg[i];
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        ch = 'a' + (ch - 'a' + key) % 26;
    } else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        ch = 'A' + (ch - 'A' + key) % 26;
    }
    msg[i] = ch;
}
printf("%s\n", msg); // kjKJ
```

<sup>*[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/BgVrbX) este código rodando*.</sup>

Ao fazer `ch - 'a'` eu "normalizo" o valor do caractere para a sua posição em relação à letra `a` (ou seja, o `a` será zero, `b` será 1, etc). Em seguida eu somo o `key` e pego o resto da divisão por 26 (assim, se o valor for resultante da soma for maior que 26 - o que significa que ultrapassaria o `z` - eu garanto que volto para o início do alfabeto). Por fim, somo o valor resultante com `a` para obter a letra correspondente. O mesmo vale para as letras maiúsculas.

---

Obs: a ideia de mapear caracteres para um valor numérico é usada até hoje, e não se limita ao ASCII (para se aprofundar no assunto, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052)).

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei nada de C ou C++, mas sei um pouco de C#, e no C# se você consegue incrementar um char, ou seja:

```
char caractere = 'A';
caractere++;
```

Fazendo isso o próprio compilador vai ler a "traduzir" a variável para ASCII, e incrementar, assim a variável caractere será B. Então acredito que seja a mesma coisa no C/C++, o if se baseia na tabela ASCII. Então se o a letra na tabela for maior que 97, que representar A em decimal, e menor que 172, que representa Z, ele continuará o código.