# Contar consoantes na frase

Tags: c

O programa deve contar o número de consoantes na frase.

Se for digitado apenas uma palavra ele conta certinho, mas se eu der espaço, ou seja, escrever uma frase ela não conta certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char vogais[]="aeiouAEIOU",frase[30];
   int vogal=0,i,j,tamanho,consoante;

   printf("Digite uma frase:");
   scanf("%[^\n]",frase);
   tamanho=strlen(frase);
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    for(j=0;j<tamanho;j++){
        if(vogais[i]==frase[j] || frase[j]==' '){
            vogal++;
        }
    }
   }
   consoante=tamanho-vogal;

   printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase:%s:%d",frase,consoante);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note que da maneira como você fez a frase é varrida várias vezes (o `for(i=0;i<10;i++){`), e portanto os eventuais espaços são contados múltiplas vezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não adianta só considerar o espaço, como feito na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448051/112052), pois se for digitado algum caractere como `@`, `%` ou `!`, ele será contabilizado como consoante. Por exemplo, se o texto digitado for `"a b c,!&defXYZ @ ABC"`, seu código diz que há 13 consoantes ([veja](https://ideone.com/vBO9iW)), pois você só considerou que os espaços não são consoantes, mas os caracteres `,`, `!`, `&` e `@` foram considerados na contagem.

O que você precisa fazer é verificar se o caractere de fato é uma letra (e no código abaixo só estou considerando letras não acentuadas do nosso alfabeto), e então descartar as vogais:

```
int main(void) {
    char frase[30];
    int consoantes = 0;

    printf("Digite uma frase:");
    scanf("%[^\n]",frase);

    for (int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++){
        char c = frase[i];
        // se for maiúscula, converte para minúscula (excluí o "A", porque nesse caso nem precisa contabilizar)
        if ('B' <= c && c <= 'Z') c += 32;
        if ('b' <= c && c <= 'z') { // só testo se estiver neste intervalo
            switch(c) { // como já deixei o "a" de fora, não preciso mais testar aqui
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    break; // se for vogal, não faz nada
                default: // é consoante
                    consoantes++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase '%s' é %d\n", frase, consoantes);
    return 0;
}
```

Agora sim ele diz corretamente que a string `"a b c,!&defXYZ @ ABC"` possui 9 consoantes, [veja](https://ideone.com/5wwC6a).

Repare que primeiro eu verifico se o `char` é letra maiúscula, e caso seja, converto-o para minúscula (só para facilitar a comparação que vem a seguir). Para entender melhor como isso funciona, dê uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446070/112052). O detalhe é que já deixei a letra "a" de fora, assim é uma letra a menos para comparar no `switch`.

Por fim, quando o código chega no bloco `switch`, naquele ponto eu tenho certeza que o `char` é uma letra minúscula de "b" a "z". Então eu só incremento o contador caso ele não seja uma vogal (e ao deixar a letra "a" de fora e converter antes para minúscula faz com que o `switch` tenha menos opções para testar, deixando o código mais sucinto - caso contrário eu teria que colocar 10 opções de `case`: as 5 vogais maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Isso é bem mais simples - e correto - do que contar a quantidade de vogais e contabilizar o espaço como se fosse uma vogal (pois só funciona se a string tiver apenas letras e espaços, qualquer outro caractere é erroneamente contabilizado como se fosse consoante).

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode combinar a função `strchr()` da bibioteca padrão `string.h` com a função `tolower()` da bilbioteca padrão `ctypes.h` para simplificar o seu algoritmo.

A função `strchr()` percorre uma string em busca do caractere especificado e retorna `NULL` caso o caractere não esteja contido dentro desta string.

A função `tolower()` converte uma letra/caractere para minúsculo.

Veja só como seu programa ficaria:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char frase[100];
    int consoantes = 0;
    char * p = frase;

    printf("Digite uma frase: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",frase);

    while(*p)
        if(strchr("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz", tolower(*p++)))
            consoantes++;

    printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase '%s' é %d\n", frase, consoantes);
    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
Digite uma frase: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma.                                    
A quantidade de consoantes na frase 'O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma.' é 10
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UnluckyTrustworthyTab)

Você poderia até mesmo implementar uma função exclusivamente responsável pela contagem de consoantes em uma string, possibilitando sua reusabilidade:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int contar_consoantes(const char * s)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(*s)
        if(strchr("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz", tolower(*s++)))
            n++;
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    char frase[100];
    printf("Digite uma frase: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",frase);
    printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase '%s' é %d\n", frase, contar_consoantes(frase));
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UnwillingVividTransversals)

E finalmente, um exemplo completo e simplificado:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define eh_consoante(letra) (strchr("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz", tolower(letra))!=NULL)
#define eh_vogal(letra) (strchr("aeiou", tolower(letra))!=NULL)

int contar_consoantes(const char * frase)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(*frase)
        if(eh_consoante(*frase++))
            n++;
    return n;
}

int contar_vogais(const char * frase)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(*frase)
        if(eh_vogal(*frase++))
            n++;
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    char frase[100];

    printf("Digite uma frase: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",frase);

    printf("Consoantes: %d\n", contar_consoantes(frase));
    printf("Vogais: %d\n", contar_vogais(frase));

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GoodNauticalUtility)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi,eu não tava me atentando era que o espaço contava como caractere,e que o tamanho da string aumentava com a tecla espaço.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char vogais[]="aeiouAEIOU",frase[30];
   int vogal=0,i,j,tamanho,consoante;

   printf("Digite uma frase:");
   scanf("%[^\n]",frase);
   tamanho=strlen(frase);
   for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
    if(frase[i]==' '){
        vogal++;
    }
   }
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    for(j=0;j<tamanho;j++){
        if(vogais[i]==frase[j]){
            vogal++;
        }
    }
   }
   consoante=tamanho-vogal;

   printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase:%s:%d",frase,consoante);












    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ainda não está certo. Se tiver outros caracteres na frase, como `,`, `.`, `@`, `!`, entre outros, a contagem sai errada, [veja](https://ideone.com/vBO9iW). Coloquei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448063/112052) que também funciona para esses casos :-)

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões,esqueci totalmente dos outros caracteres,refiz o código

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char consoantes[]="bcdfghjklmnpqrstwvxyzç",frase[30];
   int i,j,tamanho,consoante=0;

   printf("Digite uma frase:");

   scanf("%[^\n]",frase);
   tamanho=strlen(frase);
   tolower(frase);

   for(i=0;i<19;i++){
    for(j=0;j<tamanho;j++){
        if(frase[j]==consoantes[i]){
            consoante++;
        }
    }
   }


   printf("A quantidade de consoantes na frase:%s:%d",frase,consoante);












    return 0;
}
```