# Como verificar se uma ou mais string possui caractere inicial maiúsculo/minúsculo (Linguagem C)

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char leitura(const char *str){
    int i, resultado;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(str[0] >= 'A' && str[0] <= 'Z' && str[' ' + 1] >= 'A' && str[' ' + 1] <= 'Z'){
            resultado = 1;
        }else{
            resultado = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("O resultado eh: %d", resultado);
    return resultado;
}

int main(){
    char str[30];

    fgets(str, 30, stdin);
    leitura(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Essa sintaxe está certa? str[' ' + 1]. Para o compilador está tudo bem, mas não faz lógica para mim: ' ' equivale a 32 + 1 dá 33 (veja uma tabela ASCII). Se a sua str tem 30 caracteres você já ultrapassou a capacidade dela. Além disso para que colocar em um loop se o conteúdo do seu if é constante para todo valor de i.

Answer (score 2):

Para começar, `str[' ' + 1]` não faz sentido. Isso não faz o que você espera (provavelmente você pensou que seria uma posição depois do espaço, ou algo assim?) - na verdade, `char` e `int` são meio que "intercambiáveis" em C (`char`, apesar do nome, [é um tipo numérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178483/112052)). No caso, o caractere `' '` é o espaço em branco, cujo código na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) é 32, então na verdade você está tentando acessar a posição 33 de `str`:

```
// imprimir como char
printf("%c\n", ' ' + 1); // !
// imprimir como inteiro
printf("%d\n", ' ' + 1); // 33
```

E como `str` foi declarado com 30 posições, tentar acessar uma posição além deste limite gera um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/112052) (leia mais a respeito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137157/no-out-of-bounds-error)).

Outro detalhe é que no *loop* você está verificando sempre `str[0]` (a primeira posição de `str`) mas na verdade você deveria usar o `i`, pois é para isso que ele serve: para iterar pelos caracteres de `str`.

---

Além disso, o título está confuso. Se você quer verificar se a string "*possui caractere inicial maiúsculo/minúsculo*", não bastaria verificar o primeiro caractere? Aí nem precisaria de um *loop*:

```
char str[30];
fgets(str, 30, stdin);

if ('A' <= str[0] && str[0] <= 'Z') {
    // primeiro caractere é letra maiúscula
} else if ('a' <= str[0] && str[0] <= 'z') {
    // primeiro caractere é letra minúscula
} else {
    // primeiro caractere não é letra maiúscula nem minúscula
}
```

Ou - baseado na [primeira versão do título](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/467383/1) - você quer ver se tem alguma palavra que começa com maiúscula?

Nesse caso, uma forma simples é verificar, para cada caractere, se além de ser uma letra maiúscula, o caractere anterior não é uma letra. Algo assim:

```
int maiuscula(char c) {
    return 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z';
}

int letra(char c) {
    return ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || maiuscula(c);
}

int main() {
    char str[30];
    fgets(str, 30, stdin);
    int encontrou = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (maiuscula(str[i]) && (i == 0 || !letra(str[i - 1]))) {
            encontrou = 1;
            break; // se já encontrei, nem precisa continuar procurando
        }
    }
    if (encontrou) {
        printf("Encontrei\n");
    } else{
        printf("Não encontrei\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Se eu encontrar uma palavra que começa com maiúscula, eu interrompo o *loop*, pois entendi que se encontrar uma já é o suficiente e não precisa continuar procurando por outras.

Criei funções para verificar se um `char` é uma letra maiúscula, ou uma letra qualquer. No `for`, a verificação é feita no `if`, que verifica duas condições:

- `maiuscula(str[i])`: verifica se a letra atual é maiúscula
- `i == 0 || !letra(str[i - 1])`: verifica se é o primeiro caractere da string (`i == 0`), **ou** se o anterior não é letra (o operador `||` é o "ou", e o operador `!` é a negação, então `!letra(str[i - 1])` verifica se o caractere na posição `i - 1` não é uma letra)

Ambas as condições acima devem ocorrer para entrar no `if`, pois usei o operador `&&` ("and"). Ou seja, se não for uma letra maiúscula, ou se for, mas não é o primeiro ou o anterior é uma letra, não entra no `if`.

Assim o código fica mais genérico do que se considerar apenas espaços para separar as palavras (a string pode ser algo como `"-blablabla,Etc"` por exemplo - como não foi especificado nenhum detalhe a respeito, é melhor assumir que o usuário pode digitar "qualquer coisa").

---

Em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467407/112052) (atualmente apagada) sugeriu-se que em vez do `for`, se usasse aritmética de ponteiros. Ou seja, algo assim:

```
int maiuscula(char c) {
    return 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z';
}

int letra(char c) {
    return ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || maiuscula(c);
}

int temInicialMaiuscula(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if ((i++ == 0 || !letra(*(str - 1))) && maiuscula(*str)) {
            return 1; // se já encontrei, nem precisa continuar procurando
        }
        str++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char str[30];
    fgets(str, 30, stdin);
    if (temInicialMaiuscula(str)) {
        printf("Encontrei\n");
    } else{
        printf("Não encontrei\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Que faz basicamente a mesma coisa da versão anterior (a lógica principal é a mesma). A diferença é que, em vez de fazer um `for` pelos índices da string, usou-se aritmética de ponteiros para fazer com que a cada iteração `str` aponte para o próximo caractere. Para entender melhor, sugiro ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/112052).

---

Outra opção é inverter a lógica: primeiro eu vejo se o caractere atual não é letra, e caso não seja, eu vejo se o próximo é maiúscula:

```
int temInicialMaiuscula(char *str) {
    while (1) {
        if (! letra(*str)) { // se caractere atual não é letra, verifica o próximo
            str++;
            if (! *str) // chegou no final da string
                return 0;
            if (maiuscula(*str))
                return 1; // encontrei palavra que começa com maiúscula, retorna
        } else str++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu programa está bem complicado e não entendi mesmo.
Pode usar algo simples como

```
int inicial_minuscula(const char* str)
{
   return (((*str) >= 'a') && ((*str) <= 'z'));
};
```

E

```
int inicial_maiuscula(const char* str)
{
    return (((*str) >= 'A') && ((*str) <= 'Z'));
};
```

Apenas